# How can I filter wordpress custom post types with the URL?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, url-rewriting, filtering

I'm trying to filter a custom post type more effectively with the URL in wordpress but it's not quite working right.

I'd like to use links like the following:

http://www.georgiancollege.ca/athletics/events/?year=2012&cat=barrie+fitness,orillia

Which should pull all the 'event' posts from 2012 that are either both barrie and fitness or just orillia however, it simply redirects to here:

http://www.georgiancollege.ca/athletics/2012/?cat=barrie%20fitness%2Corillia

So it removes the /events directory appends /2012 and then adds the category filter - so nows it's going to the blog posts archive page instead of the events archive...

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the Events categories are not called 'cat' so I can accomplish what I need using the proper name 'eab_events_category' like so:

http://www.georgiancollege.ca/athletics/events/2012/?eab_events_category=barrie+fitness